# Find $g(2002)$ given $f(1)$ and two inequalities

Tags: functional-inequalities

It is given that $f(x)$ is a function defined on $\mathbb{R}$, satisfying $f(1)=1$ and for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$,
$$f(x+5)\geq f(x)+5,$$
$$f(x+1)\leq f(x)+1.$$
If $g(x)=f(x)+1-x$ then find $g(2002)$.

Here,
$$f(x+5)\leq f(x+4) +1,$$
I didn't get any idea..

Comment: $f(x)=x$ trivially satisfies the requirement and this example gives $g(x)$ constantly equal to $1$. Are there other examples of solution?

Answer (score 4):

Rewriting the given inequalities in terms of $\,f(x)=g(x)+x-1\,$:

$$\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
f(x+5)\geq f(x) + 5 \quad&\iff\quad g(x+5)+\bcancel{x}+\cancel{5}- \xcancel{1} \ge g(x) + \bcancel{x} -\xcancel{1} + \cancel{5} \\
 &\iff\quad g(x+5) \ge g(x) \\
f(x+1)\leq f(x)+1 \quad&\iff\quad g(x+1)+\bcancel{x}+\cancel{1}- \xcancel{1} \le g(x) + \bcancel{x} -\xcancel{1} + \cancel{1} \\
 &\iff\quad g(x+1) \le g(x) \\
\end{align}
$$

It follows that $\,\color{blue}{g(x)} \ge g(x+1) \ge g(x+2) \ge g(x+3) \ge g(x+4) \ge g(x+5) \ge \color{blue}{g(x)}\,$, so equalities must hold throughout, then $\,g(x+1)=g(x)\,$, and $\,g(2002)=g(2001)=\ldots =g(1)\,$.

Answer (score 3):

You are in the right direction, just carry on:

$$f(x+5)\leq f(x+4) +1\leq f(x+3) +2\leq f(x+2) +3\leq f(x+1) +4\leq f(x) +5$$

Observe something fishy between the LHS and the RHS here? What can you say about $f(x)$ now?

Comment: From the condition given in the ques, 
$$f(x+5)\geq f(x)+5$$ 
and from  your answer
$$f(x+5)\leq f(x)+5$$?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... What does that imply? Equality holds instead of inequality

Comment: @user471651, I didn't understand. Could you please elabotate?

Comment: @MathLover, How do we get $f(x)$ from this?

Comment: @blue_eyed_... Note that whatever methods I used to derive at my inequality were _valid_, so the end inequality is also _valid_. And, obviously, the other inequality given in the question is _valid_ as well. So, what is the only way to validate both the inequalities simultaneously?